# need to copy string to array using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a following string "url":"gangafresh.com",
an other example "url":"someexample.com",

So I need to copy those strings with URLs to an array. I guess I have to use regular expression, but the problem is I can't figure out which one will do the job.

Comment: Why you need regex here?? Is your string is simple string??

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Because as an input I am getting a 2000 symbol string and those urls are different.

Comment: i assume you are getting an Json, if you are check out json_decode($jsonString, true). If not, please supply more information, maybe a bigger chunk from the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression to capture the urls:

`/"url":"(\S+)"/g`